# Is it possible to get the "resolved" type of a promise?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have a function that's defined like this from a library.

```
export declare const getUser: (id: string) => Promise<User>;
```

I am trying to get the type of what the promise resolves.

I am able to do the following to get the promise:

```
const fetchUserSuccess = createAction(
  'users/GET_ONE_SUCCESS',
  (user: ReturnType<typeof API.getUser>) => user,
);
```

However, this will simply give me `Promise<User>` for the `user` output, when I need to extract `User`

is this possible to do with typescript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a conditional type:

```
export type UnBoxPromise<T> = T extends Promise<infer U> ? U : never;
export declare const getUser: (id: string) => Promise<User>;
const fetchUserSuccess = createAction(
    'users/GET_ONE_SUCCESS',
    (user: UnBoxPromise<ReturnType<typeof getUser>>) => user,
);
```